# AngularJs -What is the most efficient way to watch an object for newly added child property?

Tags: angularjs

I want to watch an object for new child properties that get added to the object. What would be the correct way to do so? I tried watching the object by iteratively comparing the keys of the new object to the old object as follows , but it does not appear to detect new keys.

```
$scope.$watchCollection("ObjectToBeWatched", function (newObj, oldObj) {
            for (newkey in newObj) {

                var found = false;

                for (oldkey in oldObj) {
                    if (newkey == oldkey) {
                        found = true;
                        console.log('found is true');
                        break;
                    };
                };
                if (found)
                {
                    console.log('found');
                    continue; //iterate the next new val

                }
                else //this key is new
                {

                    console.log(newkey);

                } 
            }; // end for newkey
        });
```

Comment: I logged both old and new objects but they are the both identical and have the new property??? How is that happening? console.log(oldObj);console.log(newObj);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in `$watchCollection` where it will return the same properties for `newCollection` and `oldCollection` (as you are encountering now).

See these issues talking about the problem:

- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5661
- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2621
- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5688

You should be able to manually detect the changes by keeping a copy of the previous `newCollection` and doing your comparison logic against that (instead of relying on the `oldCollection` passed in by Angular):

**EDIT:** To work correctly you will need to use `oldCollection = angular.clone(newCollection)`, otherwise we can't detect property changes.

```
var oldCollection;
$scope.$watchCollection(collection, function(newCollection){
    // TODO: Perform your checking between `newCollection` and the cached `oldCollection` values.

    // Save the 'newCollection' values for comparison next time.
    // NOTE: Make sure to clone the object so newCollection !== oldCollection.
    oldCollection = angular.copy(newCollection);
});
```

Here is an example of how you might manually go about detecting changes to the properties:

```
var oldCollection = {};
$scope.$watchCollection('o', function(newCollection) {
    // Collect the new/old properties.
    var change = {
        added: {},
        deleted: {},
        changed: {}
    };

    if (oldCollection) {
        // Check newCollection and oldCollection.
        for (var i in newCollection) {
            if (oldCollection.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                if (oldCollection[i] !== newCollection[i]) {
                    change.changed[i] = true;
                }
            } else {
                change.added[i] = true;
            }
        }

        for (var i in oldCollection) {
            if (!newCollection.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                change.deleted[i] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    oldCollection = angular.copy(newCollection);
});
```

Comment: +1 and Thanks!!! you nailed the problem/solution - copying the object manually did the trick. It works now! - Any further suggestions to improve the efficiency of the algorithm for large collections would be welcome.

Comment: You could probably speed things up by writing a custom watch function that will watch for changes as well as track the property changes. That way you don't have to iterate over all the properties as many times.

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.$watch("ObjectToBeWatched",function(newObj,oldObj){

},true);
```

Since you're deep watching you need to pass true as the last parameter to your `watch`.
On the performance note, deep watching objects is computationally expensive, `$watchCollection` doesn't deep watch objects, so it has better performance. To be honest if that's all you're doing in your watch, (the comparison) I think it'd be OK as it doesn't seem to be too expensive.

**EDIT:**
Often `$watchCollection` doesn't work the way you expect it to, as in your case, I've seen issues raised on the angular github repo that `$watchCollection` is not working as intended. I find that `$watch` almost always works, I've shown this in the plunk below, if you try using `$watchCollection` it won't work.
Try this:

```
  $scope.$watch("ObjectToBeWatched", function (newObj, oldObj) {
    for (var property in newObj) {
      if (!oldObj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        console.log("new addition is :"+ property);
      }
    }
  },true);
```

It also depends if you're watching a collection, or an object, I use `$watchCollection` for watching multiple properties in an object or array. [Here is a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/eCNA0IdcxVtOxMfIc2m2?p=info) demonstrating what you need to do. Also, note that if you remove the true parameter from the watch the changes are not logged. A word about performance, the impact depends greatly on how big the object you're watching is and how often that object changes, the performance overhead in that plunk is negligible because the object is small and 2 seconds is a long time, but you need to look at your particular scenario, if you're adding items to an array not an object, then yea `$watchCollection` is the way to go.

Comment: Nope, I already tried setting deep watch and it does not work.

Comment: Also, I am only interested in watching the direct child properties, so deep watch should not be relevant.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your inputs. However, I used the approach described by Sly_cardinal while using $watchCollection.

Answer (score 1):

Most efficient way to watch an object properties is with `$watchCollection`. from the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope) :

> $watchCollection(obj, listener); 
>   Shallow watches the properties of an
>   object and fires whenever any of the properties change (for arrays,
>   this implies watching the array items; for object maps, this implies
>   watching the properties). If a change is detected, the listener
>   callback is fired.

Good tutorial and comparison can be found [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-Scope-watch-vs-watchCollection-In-AngularJS.htm).

Comment: I am already using $watchCollection per the code I posted. The question is about achieving efficiencies in the use case, beyond just using watchCollection.

Comment: Yea $watchColletcion is more performant, but it's not detecting new additions to the object. I've had this issue with $watchCollection before, not sure if its a bug.